# What is the math behind the profile's "Fleet Power"

Tags: azur-lane

If you go to your "resume" or profile page you will see your stats, like so:

[image: The player's stat page in-game]

All of those stats are easy to know where the values are from, except one, the **Fleet Power**.

Yes, it's as simple as leveling up every ship you have and the more powerful they get this number rises. **But how?**

So I logged every ship's total stats value in a table (a spreadsheet to be exact) and got these stats:

[image: Logged data of stats]

None of these values are near Fleet power, the closest is `Max`.

**How does the game determine this value?**

---

**Update** on Oct 2, 2019

I decided to create a new account just to have a empty dock and for easy logging of ships to calculate.

I played for a bit and got a few ships and I recorded their stats.

[image: Logged data of stats in my new account]

Now here's the problem. My Fleet Power is **417**. It's below every single stats on my fleet, a complete opposite on my main account which has higher FP than the recorded stats.

I played a bit more and tried to enhance one of my ships by using some low rarity ones, I used 6 of them and recorded my ship's stats once more,

[image: Logged data of stats after some changes]

By doing so, my Fleet Power dropped to 297. Which only means, **the game takes into account the number of your ships you have into calculating FP.**

My question still remains unchanged.

---

**Update** on Oct 6, 2019

This time I decided to now include the levels of my ships as I think they are weighted based of that, I noticed it when responding to the comments below.

> As for the upgrades/equipment, it does affect FP, for example, removing one in the highest stat ship reduces her stats by 400, and the FP reduces by 4; on the lowest stat ship, removing all of her equipment drops her stat my 200, but no effect on the FP at all

As before, I logged the data of my ships, with levels included:

[image: Logged data of stats and levels]

I have decided to just change the ship's equipment and see the ship's stats and Fleet Power difference since its the easiest way of doing it (and I lack the in-game resources to do so). After a couple of minutes, I ended up with these stats:

[image: Select ship's data after some changes]

What I got with the results is **the FP changes by ~1 by every ~100 change to the ship's stats regardless of level**. My claim of the ships is being weighted is false.

Seeing that the ratio of Fleet power to ship stats is 1:100, it doesn't make sense, since that only means the `Total Raw Ship power` I have is just being divided by 100. 3246 is no where near 4686.

I tried other dumb formulas to get the value near Fleet Power, which is 4686.
As a disclaimer, I'm not really good at doing/finding formulas.

In the following examples, I'm going to use variables in for ease.

The Variables:

```
FP     = 4686          (Fleet Power)

TSP    = 324698        (Total Ship Power)
SPC    = 251           (Ships Count)
AVGSP  = 1293.61753    (TSP / SPC  or average of ship power)
SPMAX  = 4182          (Max Ship Power)
SPMIN  = 397           (Min Ship Power)
SPDEV  = 863.0374934   (Standard Deviation from TSP's data set)

TLVL   = 11253         (Total Levels of Ships)
AVGLVL = 44.83266932   (TLVL / SPC or average level)
LVLMAX = 107           (Max Ship level)
LVLMIN = 1             (Min ship level)
LVLDEV = 29.21239272   (Standard Deviation from TLVL's data set)
```

Now for the formulas I've tried:

```
=(TSP / 100) + SPDEV 
Result: 4110.017193

=(TSP / 100) + ((SPMAX + SPMIN) / SPC) + SPDEV
Result: 4128.260221

=(TSP / 100) + AVGSP 
Result: 4540.59753 (close!)

=(TSP / 100) + AVGSP + LVLMAX
Result: 4647.59753 (Even closer!)

=(TSP / 100) + AVGSP + LVLMAX + AVGLVL
Result: 4692.430199 (Went past, but close.)

=(TSP / 100) + AVGSP + LVLMAX + LVLDEV
Result: 4676.809923 (The closest I've got, only away by 10!)
```

The last formula is the closest for sure, but I am not satisfied by it and I haven't tested it on my other accounts due to lack of time.

If anyone would be interested to all of my data gathered for this question, [here's the Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1deOzcCzrsa8ELg78pzv-N8psniQ2l8ddvrHatsppV8o/edit?usp=sharing) I used.

Comment: If you have a single ship, what's it say? ... Does each ship add a predetermined value?

Comment: The minimum allowed number of ships is two, and after the tutorial and scrapped the newly received ships, the Fleet Power is 122. I constructed a new one, totaling 3 ships now, the FP rises to 159. Scrapping that new ship again drops the FP to 122. The FP calculation seems to follow some predetermined formula, based on the number of ships you have and the individual stat of a ship.

Comment: If you have 2 / 3 of the same ship, is the FP a multiple of 2 or 3?

Comment: After getting 9 new ships, 2 of which are duplicates, the FP is now 362, a multiple of 2.

Comment: I meant when your only ships are just copies of the same ship, but on average, it seems like a ship is worth about 50 / 60 FP. ....Also see how certain upgrades affect FP?

Comment: I also tried this on my main account just to see the values, starting at 4641 FP, a new ship increases it to 4647, just 6FP, which kinda invalidates your claim of 50/60FP per ship (its only applicable at low ship count) It looks like the more ships you have, the less impact a new ship would have at FP as if the ships are weighted. ...As for the upgrades/equipment, it does affect FP, for example, removing one in the highest stat ship reduces her stats by 400, and the FP reduces by 4; on the lowest stat ship, removing all of her equipment drops her stat my 200, but no effect on the FP at all...

Comment: Well, we've learned a lot, but can't make any super accurate formulae. ... Maybe add this info into the Question Body?

Comment: Will do, but I have to dig deeper on this before I edit it.

Comment: Added a bunch of information in the question.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That's so much info!

Comment: I'm wondering if Headquarters Level plays any part.

Comment: No time to conduct any "testing" but I think it looks like HQ level rounded to the nearest hundred and divided by 10 would be a perfect fit to that missing 10. Good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tl;DR:** 
The fatal flaw in your attempts to find a formula is that you assume a linear function. The function is most likely based on **c * sqrt(X)**, where X is total stats of your fleet and c is some arbitrary constant chosen by the developer.

**Long answer:**
I started playing less than two weeks ago, so I have a new account where I can do some low-end testing. I am currently much closer to ~1FP for every ~60 total stats; raising a ship's power by ~230 will give me 3-4 Fleet Power. On the other hand, if I look at the leaderboards, the top ranked players have only about 6x as much Fleet Power as me (12000 vs. 2000), but I'd expect their total stats to be at least 20 times as high as mine.

On a side note, moving all the gear from my strongest to my weakest destroyer (after stripping the weaker one down) had no effect on my Fleet Power. Javelin went from 3191 to 2039 Power (-1152), Cygnet went from 672 to 1824 (+1152), and my Fleet power remained at 2066. Dismissing duplicate ships has no effect, and neither does collecting or powering up Collab ships.

The obvious conclusion is that, the higher your total stats already are, the more stats you have to gain to increase your fleet power. This assumption should explain all the observations in your data, e.g. a new ship giving 6-7 Fleet Power early on and only 2 Fleet Power later on.

The developers have a simple reason for doing this: Making the leaderboards look less intimidating for new players and giving them the illusion that they might be able to catch up. On the other hand, there would be no reason for the devs to calculate all the different variables you gathered and plugging them into a formula.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now, I really thought the calculation is linear and the formula changes based on your player stats or something. Also, good call on powering up Collab ships, I'm kinda confused on why my FP isn't changing even though I raise them well. Thank you for your answer, marking this as accepted now.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting post and I actually found it while trying to find more info on collab ships on fleet power as my testing showed they do not have any impact and based on some replies here it only confirms that. I'll have to check how it goes with the -chan ships (EDIT: -chan ships actually contribute to fleet power, just tested) but I suspect it's the same story, likely only ships that count towards fleet tech contribute to fleet power.  I only realized it this collab which is kinda uh oh since I'm trying to maximize fleet power basically since the game launched (and I'm currently the #1 AL EN fleet power rank). But better late than never.

One thing I can add is that multiple copies of ship do not count at the same lb level. However different stages of LB will each contribute to FP. So to max fleet power you will need 4 copies of each ship at 4 different LB levels. In other words 11 copies of each ship (or bulin combinations), 1, 1+1, 1+2, 1+4.

Another factor that contributes to FP are the bonuses from fleet tech.

Comment: I didn't know that similar ships that have different LB level contributes to the FP, that's new knowledge.